# Measuring voltage with different voltmeters in parallel - influences?

Tags: voltage-measurement, voltmeter

Let's say we're measuring voltage of a battery with three different voltmeters in parallel, as is shown in the picture:

[image]

Would those voltmeters influence each other because of their finite internal resistances? 
I'm thinking that, since they're all in parallel, it won't matter how big their internal resistances are, and thus, won't influence each other in therms of that. The reading of each individual voltmeter will only be influenced by themselves (their internal resistances, accuracy, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, if the internal resistances of the meters were infinite it would make no difference.

However, since they are not infinite each meter draws a very small current from the battery. Since the battery has a terminal resistance, that means the more meters you add the lower the voltage that will be present at the terminals of the battery, and the lower the readings on the meters.

To be pedantic, the way you have shown them wired also means that there is three meter currents in the first wires, two in the second, and obviously one in the last. If there is any significant resistance in the wire, that would introduce additional voltage drops into the system.

But, unless you are using three really bad meters with horribly thin wires, or the battery resistance has gone really high, you should not notice much, if any, difference caused by the setup itself.

Of course, like the old adage.."Man with two watches never knows the right time.." Each meter will have it's own inaccuracy, and having three meters won't get you a better reading.

Comment: If we ignore the resistance in the wire, will all three voltmeters always show the same voltage?

Comment: @A6ETF probably not simply because they will be calibrated differently. Should be close though.

Answer (score 1):

They will be influenced, assuming the voltage source has a non-zero source impedance.  If you redraw the diagram with the parasitic resistors (one in series with the voltage source and one in parallel with each voltmeter) the effects will be more obvious, the source impedance is what makes your parallel analysis invalid

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyu719.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

.  For typical real-world situations these effects will be minimal as the source impedance will be at most a few ohms and the equivalent resistance of the voltmeters will be in the multiple-gigaohm range.

Comment: "the equivalent resistance of the voltmeters will be in the multiple-gigaohm range" Not quite common, unless you are so rich to place three bench DMMs in parallel. Most common decent hand-held DMMs have a de-facto standard 10Mohm internal resistance. Crappy 10$ Chinese DMMs may have an internal resistance as low as 1Mohm.

Comment: True.  The cheaper the meter, the lower the internal resistance.  The cheaper the meter the less precise the meter is.  I'm pretty sure that unless you have a high source impedance on the voltage source, the measurement uncertainty of the meter will always swamp the error induced by the series resistance.  With a 2 ohm source impedance and 10Mohm meters, the error from the internal meter resistance is on the order of 10E-7.  If that error is larger than the measurement error, you have a meter impedance well over 10Mohms.